# Pandas: Merging columns in a data frame with new columns created for the common variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
ID,SomeValue,FooA1,FooA2,FooA3,FooB1,FooB2,FooB3,BarA1,BarA2,BarA3,BarB1,BarB2,BarB3
1 ,val1     ,4    ,7    ,2    ,8    ,1    ,3    ,2    ,9    ,2    ,0    ,9    ,2
2 ,val2     ,2    ,3    ,8    ,     ,     ,     ,1    ,5    ,3    ,     ,     , 
.
.
```

And I would like to merge the columns "[Foo|Bar][A|B]\d+" so that they become the following, i.e. the different combinations of the multiple columns are merged and appropriate new columns are created to contain the variable representing those variations:

```
ID,SomeValue,FooBar    ,AB    ,Num    ,Val
1 ,val1     ,Foo       ,A     ,1      ,4
1 ,val1     ,Foo       ,A     ,2      ,7
1 ,val1     ,Foo       ,A     ,3      ,2
1 ,val1     ,Foo       ,B     ,1      ,8
1 ,val1     ,Foo       ,B     ,2      ,1
1 ,val1     ,Foo       ,B     ,3      ,3
1 ,val1     ,Bar       ,A     ,1      ,2
1 ,val1     ,Bar       ,A     ,2      ,9
1 ,val1     ,Bar       ,A     ,3      ,2
1 ,val1     ,Bar       ,B     ,1      ,0
1 ,val1     ,Bar       ,B     ,2      ,9
1 ,val1     ,Bar       ,B     ,3      ,2
2 ,val2     ,Foo       ,A     ,1      ,2
2 ,val2     ,Foo       ,A     ,2      ,3
2 ,val2     ,Foo       ,A     ,3      ,8
2 ,val2     ,Bar       ,A     ,1      ,1
2 ,val2     ,Bar       ,A     ,2      ,5
2 ,val2     ,Bar       ,A     ,3      ,3
```

Note that there can be empty values, as for example in row 2 above and those should not be included in the final set.

This must be fairly simple to do, but I'm new to pandas and am struggling to find the right commands to use.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

- [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape, last `index` to column by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)
- [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extrah column with [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for parse by regex
- [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) for change columns order

---

```
df = df.set_index(['ID','SomeValue']).stack().reset_index(name='Val')
df[['FooBar','AB','Num']] = df.pop('level_2').str.extract('(Foo|Bar)(A|B)(\d+)', expand=True)
cols = ['ID', 'SomeValue', 'FooBar', 'AB', 'Num','Val']
df = df.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (df)
    ID SomeValue FooBar AB Num  Val
0    1      val1    Foo  A   1  4.0
1    1      val1    Foo  A   2  7.0
2    1      val1    Foo  A   3  2.0
3    1      val1    Foo  B   1  8.0
4    1      val1    Foo  B   2  1.0
5    1      val1    Foo  B   3  3.0
6    1      val1    Bar  A   1  2.0
7    1      val1    Bar  A   2  9.0
8    1      val1    Bar  A   3  2.0
9    1      val1    Bar  B   1  0.0
10   1      val1    Bar  B   2  9.0
11   1      val1    Bar  B   3  2.0
12   2      val2    Foo  A   1  2.0
13   2      val2    Foo  A   2  3.0
14   2      val2    Foo  A   3  8.0
15   2      val2    Foo  B   1  1.0
16   2      val2    Foo  B   2  5.0
17   2      val2    Foo  B   3  3.0
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. It wasn't so easy after all (At least for me).
I tried your solution with my dataset and the structure is good, but I get NaN for all my values.
What is 'b' in reset_index(name='b')?

Comment: Opps, typo, it is `Val`.

Comment: `NaN`s - all values are NaNs? What is `print (df.info())` of original datadarme before `set_index()` ?

Comment: Not after I replaced 'b' by 'Val', now I get some values. But I still have some mess when there are empty values. The Foo|Bar, A|B columns contain NaNs and Val contains "Foo", "Bar", "A", "B" and values, which means that merging isn't properly handled when there are empty values. Let me check the original dataframe.

Comment: what is number of columns? Because this extracting regex  sometimes can return bad values. Better is (if possible) create some separator in columns like `Foo_A_1`.

Comment: I checked the original data frame and the empty values are in fact all NaNs. Any good way of dealing with that?

Basically row 2 in my example above is:
    2 ,val2     ,2    ,3    ,8    ,NaN  ,NaN  ,NaN  ,1    ,5    ,3    ,NaN  ,NaN  ,NaN

Comment: Hmmm,it depends what need. Replace NaNs by some scalar (`df = df.fillna(0)`)? Or something else?

Comment: because function `stack` remove NaNs rows.

Comment: If check output, there are no values for `BarB1 - BarB3`, because `NaN`s in original df.

Comment: I did a d = d.replace(np.nan, '', regex=True) and it didn't change the result. I can post a sample of the actual dataframe I'm using so that you can see if there might be an issue with the names.

Comment: Problem  is you lost rows like `BarB1` - `BarB3` in sample data? Need `3` last rows?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151781/discussion-between-tamori-and-jezrael).

Comment: Give this person a big trophy for the great help s/he has given me in chat, which eventually solved my problem!

Comment: Only please no serial voting ;) [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/295067)